# Shopping Cart Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I am tasked to build a shopping cart that sells book. I would like to seek help in putting me in the right direction as to where to go from here.

As of what I see, I can do the cart in two ways:

- Use CI framework and build the site from scratch.
- Use an existing shopping cart system and build from there.

The problem with doing the CI is its very tedious. You are basically building from scratch. So this will take time and add to the fact that this is my first time building a shopping cart. The second option seems to be ok. Why would I re-invent the wheel so to say. The only problem is finding the right open source cart that is well documented for me to start on.

So based on the two options I have. If you think it is the second option, can you suggest (if you had created a cart before) a shopping cart application that is easy and the code base is similar to CI. I found OpenCart to be ok but I would like to seek other suggestions before I start.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to take into consideration here.

- What is your programming experience?

  - Have you worked with big scale web applications before? (I would say that almost all online store could be considered big scale web applications)
  - Have you worked with payment integrations?
  - Have you worked in setting up hosting environments?
- What is the budget for your project?
- Are you the only one working on the project?
- What is your client expecting from the finished product?
- When the store is online, who manages hosting, support, maintenance, etc?

Building a online store is no simple and small task. A small store with a flow like this `add product to cart -> go to checkout -> pay using a third part payment provider` could be accomplished quite easily and fast. But here are some more considerations:

- Shipping methods, should there be multiple ones?
- Must the site handle multiple countries, in that case you have to consider VAT, shipping again, etc.
- Payment options: Credit card, SMS, invoice, PayPal, and the list goes on.. What should be available? And this will require a good hosting environment if you wish to do direct implementations (SSL certificates, etc).
- Handling orders, returns and products in the backend
- Discount features, such as discount codes
- Being able to sell multiple products bundled as one.

I could go on for a while and make the list more and more specified, but I don't really have the time for that :) And this was just to show you that there are a lot of factors that comes in to play when building an online store.

### [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/)

This is an excellent choice if you are an experience developer and familiar with the Zend framework (which it's built upon). Take a look at the [features](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/enterprise-features) for Magento, pretty much anything is possible with Magento if you know how to customize it correctly. This is not an easy task if you're not familiar with it and the learning curve is very steep.

**This is a bad choice if you're not experience or the store doesn't need all of the advanced features.** It's a resource hog and if you don't know your caching you will have a bad time.

### [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/)

If you need to setup a online store in a hurry with a stable environment and you can settle with having the [features](http://www.shopify.com/tour/sell-online) they offer, I would say this is your best choice. Well actually I would say that at least 90% of the times, this would be the best choice.

You won't have to worry about payment implementations, backend development, support, hosting, and all the other things that comes into play.

### Conclusion

I've only listed 2 options here, one advanced and one more simple on. I think you should really investigaste the different options. Take a look at their features, how much they cost, etc. Then you have to take that into consideration vs the time it will take for you to complete the store.

At least I hope I gave you some perspective on this, just let me know if you have any questions on what I wrote.

Comment: I am not creating my store so shopify is not a doable solution. It is a task that was given to me to do, so I would at least develop it to an extent. I am the only one creating this, and the time isn't much of a factor, so I have time to learn to create one. I would be using external payment system, particularly paypal for this. The product will be digital, so after the payment, the user will be able to download the file after payment. It just a store selling online books. Nothing more.

Comment: I wouldn't suggesting anyone working alone to write an online store from scratch or setup one using a platform. Because there's a lot of work even after the site goes live. Payments can fail, hosting can fail, anything connected to it can fail. I'm really not trying to be an ass here, it's just that I have very bad experiences from this and I don't want you to make the same ones :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Someone will review the code and do some testing before going live. I think this is just a test for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Zend Framework to building shopping cart site. If you want to build from existing tool use Magento. Check [Front End](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/)  and [admin end](http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/index.php/admin/) here

You can create your custom module or download free modules and can purchase  developed module from magento.

Comment: Check this http://dineshkumarm.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/add-product-to-cart-using-multi-dimensional-array/  if you want to create from core php

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options

1. Magento
2. Opencart

Both of them are built for e-commerce.

Magento is slow without any doubt, opencart is fast but not the best as Magento.

If your's application scope is limited, you can build the application in CI and i knows that it will be faster than both of these two.

But as programming perspective, its always better which is already build instead starting from scratch.

Comment: What would I miss if I choose Opencart vs Magneto?

Comment: Also, If I build from scratch the problem that I would face is putting, let's say, PayPal for the payment system. Any documentation on setting this up?

Comment: If you use magento, you just need to create some plugins if required.. same about the opencart.. but yet i am in favor of magento without any reason :) ..